# Is there any way to re-use the layers of a built docker image on multiple machines?

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile that lives on two machines, machines A and B.

On machine A I build the docker file up to stage n.
On machine B, I want to build up to stage n+1, re-using the layers from machine A up to stage n.

How can this be accomplished?

I have tried making use of `docker image save` (on machine A) and `docker image load` (on machine B), but I can't seem to extract the layers from the `save`'s resulting `.tar`.

In this particular case, I do not want to use a docker registry.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @snahor No error, it's just that the layers from the `docker image load` are not being used when re-building on machine B.  It builds everything from scratch.